# Radiometric standardization for Landsat5 and Landsat8

Tags: classification, landsat, land-cover, land-classification, landsat-5

I'm currently encountering an issue with classifying LULC. The first image I have is a false color composite taken in 2020 using Landsat 8. However, the second image, captured in 2010 using Landsat 5, does not display the expected cyan blue color and appears to have dull colors overall. I'm seeking guidance on how to address this situation. Should I perform contrast stretching? If so, could anyone suggest a tutorial or provide some guidance on how to proceed?

[image]